# Loopback remoteMethod with onesignal push notification

Tags: loopback

i still learn, and trying to be learn. im looking for trying hard remote method on loopback 3 for push notification to specific user with onesignal.

any wrong in my code ?
because always :

> Error: [ 'All included players are not subscribed' ]

My Case :

1. im using ionic 3 framework
2. loopback 3 (or latest)
3. 2 User, (Customer & Seller)
4. Customer buying product from thread's seller.
5. If success to order, the seller will receive the notification.

and This is My code :

```
    Ajiorder.observe('after save', function (ctx, next) {
        console.log('Order', ctx.instance);
        let postingModel = app.models.AjiPosting;
        let userAuth = app.models.AjiUserAuth;

        postingModel.find({
            where:
            { id: ctx.instance.id }
        }, function (err, success) {
            console.log(success, 'SUKSES');
            if (ctx.instance) {
                let dataFilter = [];
                dataFilter.push({
                    'field': 'tag',
                    'key': 'id',
                    'relation': '=',
                    'value': success[0].id
                });
                console.log(success[0].idSeller, 'ID TOT')
                console.log(dataFilter, 'dataFilter');

                let data = {
                    idSeller: ctx.instance.idSeller
                }
                console.log(data, 'Data');
                userAuth.find({
                    where:
                    { id: ctx.instance.idCustomer }
                }, function (err, result) {
                    console.log(result, 'Data Personal');

                    let content = result[0].namaLengkap + ' ' + 'Order your product';
                    console.log(content, 'Nama Order');
                    console.log(ctx.instance.idSeller, 'My Dream', success[0].id);
                    if (ctx.instance.id != success[0].id) {
                        console.log('Spirit');
                        sendMessage(dataFilter, content, data);
                    }
                })
            }
            next();
        });
    });

    var sendMessage = function (device, message, data) {

        var restKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        var appID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
        request(
            {
                method: 'POST',
                uri: 'https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications',
                headers: {
                    'authorization': 'Basic ' + restKey,
                    'content-type': 'application/json'
                },
                json: true,
                body: {
                    'app_id': appID,
                    'filters': device,
                    'data': data,
                    'contents': { en: message }
                }
            },
            function (error, response, body) {
                try {
                    if (!body.errors) {
                        console.log(body);
                    } else {
                        console.error('Error:', body.errors);
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }

            }
        )
    }
};
```

and i got this error :

> Error: [ 'All included players are not subscribed' ]

Picture : [Picture of Console Log Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNYJ4.png)

any one can help me ?
sorry for my english too bad.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Solved !

I'm Forget to add some code from onesignal. thanks